# How do I convert this for loop into a while loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I am creating an array program. I am practicing how to convert `for` loops to `while` loops, but I cannot grasp the concept.

If I have the `for` loop:

```
int [] list = new int [5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    list [i] = i + 2;
}
```

How would I make it a `while` loop?

Here's my attempt

```
int [] list = new int [5];
int i = 0;

while (i<5) {
    list [i] = i + 2;
    i++;
}
System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
```

This is what I think should be done, but it comes up as an error in my computer.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 at Arrays2.main(Arrays2.java:21)

This is line 21

```
System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
```

Comment: First, make it a valid for loop.

Comment: I have an attempt! Should I post it here or on the question?

Comment: Now please describe why that doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: "but it comes up as an error in my computer" What error? Looks fine to me.

Comment: If you get an error, post the complete error message and more pertinent code. Strive to post only well-formatted code please.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `int[] list = new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };`

Comment: The only **error** I see is `for (int = i; i < 5; i++) {` which should *probably* be `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {`

Comment: When I attempt to print out the numbers of the array, there is a syntax error indicated as an out of bounds.

Comment: @MouseEvent Good catch. That's the one. :)

Comment: @A.S. `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list))` **or** post the code that is ***failing*** (the `print`).

Comment: That is not a syntax error. A syntax error would be notified when **compiling** the code. A "out of bounds" is an exception that happens at runtime, when **running** the code. Post the **complete and exact** error message.

Comment: I am unsure of how to post the error. I apologize!! This is my first year in computer science and my first time using this website.

Comment: @A.S. simple: you copy the code that causes the error and you paste  it in your question, as code. Then you copy the complete error stack trace and you paste it in your question.

Comment: Well, if you get an error when _printing_ the array, maybe you should show us _that_ code instead of the while loop that's perfectly fine...

Comment: What is the 21st line of your code?

Comment: Read the error message. It tells you that the error is at line 21. It tells you that the wrong index is 5 (which is correct, since the last index of an array of length 5 is 4), and it tells you that the error is an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: that name is self-explanatory, but you can browse the javadoc of that class to see what it means. That should be more than enough to let you find your mistake.

Comment: The print code by itself doesn't tell enough. It's likely in a loop that has not be constructed correctly. Show that.

Comment: is the print code ___after___ the increment???

Comment: @MouseEvent: good point, and god knows.

Comment: That error doesn't make sense, your code is perfectly fine (just ran it), make sure you have line numbers displayed and look where line 21 is (from: `Arrays2.java:21` in your error) and make sure that the line that causes the error is in the question. Also you can add comment `//this is line 21` for us to know where is the problem

Comment: @kajacx it makes perfect sense: after the loop, `i`'s value is 5, and thus accessing `list[i]` causes an exception, since the length of list is 5.

Comment: line 21 in my program is the print statement. is there a difference in a print statement from a for loop to a while loop?

Comment: @A.S. no, there is no difference, just as there is no difference between a print statement inside and outside any type of loop.

Comment: I am still unable to understand why there is an error in my program then. Thank you for all your help, I can ask my teacher tomorrow. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

The general structure of a basic for statement is:

```
for ( ForInit ; Expression ; ForUpdate ) Statement
```

- `ForInit` is the initializer. It is run first to set up variables etc.
- `Expression` is a boolean condition to check to see if `Statement` should be run
- `Statement` is the block of code to be run if `Expression` is true
- `ForUpdate` is run after the `Statement` to e.g. update variables as necessary

After `ForUpdate` has been run, `Expression` is evaluated again. If it is still true, `Statement` is executed again, then `ForUpdate`; repeat this until `Expression` is false.

You can restructure this as a while loop as follows:

```
ForInit;
while (Expression) {
  Statement;
  ForUpdate;
}
```

In order to apply this pattern to a "real" for loop, just substitute your blocks as described above.

For your example above:

- `ForInit` => `int i = 0`
- `Expression` => `i < 5`
- `ForUpdate` => `i++`
- `Statement` => `list [i] = i + 2;`

Putting it together:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
  list[i] = i + 2;
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int [] list = new int [5];

int i = 0; // initialization
while (i < 5) { // condition
    list [i] = i + 2;
    i++; // afterthought
}
```

The for loop posted is pretty much a shorthand for the above. The first part of a for loop is called the initialization, equivalent to the `int i = 0;`  in the above code. The next is called the condition, which, if true, will cause the loop to be run again; this is the `i < 5` part. Finally there is the afterthought, which changes the iterator `i` (usually an increment of one for iterating over an array). The for loop simply condenses these three parts into one line, as such:

```
for (initialization; condition; afterthought) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop is perfetly fine, but after it ends, the value of `i` is `5`. Since java arrays are always indexed from zero, `list[5]` doesn't exist and accessing it throws exception.

That's what you see when printing `System.out.print(list[i] + " ");` Just print any other element, `list[1]`, `list[4]` or `list[0]` for example.