# Why isn't my for loop looping? My for loop line is considered dead code

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm unsure as to why Eclipse is saying that "i++" is dead code and why i is not being incremented.

```
for(int i = 0; i < holdings.length; i++)
            {
                if(holdings[i].holdingID.equals(userHoldingIDInput) == true)
                {
                    holdings[i].print();
                    System.out.println();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("The Holding ID you entered was not found,"
                            + " please try again." + "\n");
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Can someone please explain to my what I've done wrong and a solution? Thank you!

Comment: Note: `if (something == true)` is redundant: you can just write `if (something)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I forgot to remove that, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of the branches in the conditional end with a return:

```
if (...) {
  // ...
  return;
} else {
  // ...
  return;
}
```

so `i++` would never be incremented.

Note that the general structure of a [basic `for` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) is:

```
for ( ForInit ; Expression ; ForUpdate ) Statement
```

which is [equivalent to the `while` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36023451/3788176):

```
{
  ForInit;
  while (Expression) {
    Statement;
    ForUpdate;
  }
}
```

So if `Statement` unconditionally returns, `ForUpdate` is never executed, and so it has been correctly identified as dead code.

---

I am not sure exactly what you intend to do, but I think that your `else` branch should actually be outside the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < holdings.length; i++) {
  if (holdings[i].holdingID.equals(userHoldingIDInput)) {
    // ...
    return;
  }
}
System.out.println("The Holding ID you entered was not found,"
                        + " please try again." + "\n");
return;  // Might be unnecessary; depends upon what follows.
```

Comment: Oooooh. I added the return because I thought it fixed an issue I had earlier but it only created another problem. Thank you!

Comment: Even though you don't know what I intend to do with the code, putting the else branch outside of the for loop andkeeping the return in the if statement actually fixed some other problems I was having with my program so thank you once again!

Comment: @C.Smith you're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from both of your conditions.
i++ would get evaluate on the next iteration of the loop.Since that is never going to happen , your IDE is suggesting it is a dead code.