# Java - my while loop works, but my for loop doesn't - having trouble converting it

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I assume that if I can't convert my while loop into a for loop, then I don't fully understand the concepts here. Here's my working while loop:

(I am trying to implement a program, which calculates the sum 1+2+3+...+n where n is given as user input.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int number = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());

        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;

        while (i < number) {
            i++;
            sum += i;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
```

I was looking at this user's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36023451/11522261
and tried to implement it, but it's not working.

```
.....
for (i = 0; i < number; i++){
            sum += i;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
```

It looks like the conditions of `For Init` `expression` `statement` and `ForUpdate` are set right, but I'm having trouble understanding the differences here.

Also, it looks like this exercise is trying to teach loops to solve iterative problems. But I suspect that this isn't helping me practice recursion. Perhaps there is a recursive solution to this problem which would be better. Just thinking out loud here. Thanks!

Comment: Why was my question downvoted?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder right, I did not want to write it out, just like IMHO is better not worded.

Comment: Downvoting can also happen on not finding the question very challenging or the problem exemplary. Here incrementing before or after summing i. Nothing important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that in your `while` loop, you're incrementing `i` **before** adding it to `sum`, but in your `for` loop, it's after.

If the `while` is producing the right result, you can adjust your `for` by starting at 1 instead of 0 and continuing while `<= number` instead of `< number`.

For completeness, here's how your current `for` loop works:

1. `i = 0`
2. If `i < number` is **not** true, exit the loop; otherwise, continue to Step 3
3. `sum += i` (`i` is still `0`)
4. `i++`
5. Goto Step 2

On the second pass, `i < number` is `1 < number` so still `true` if `number` is greater than 1, so you go to Step 3, do `sum += i` while `i` is `1`, then continue.

Eventually `i < number` isn't true anymore, and the loop exits.

---

For problems like this, the best approach is usually to use the debugger built into your IDE to step through the code statement by statement, looking at the values of variables as you go. That can reveal how things work really well. This article may be helpful: [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

Use <= instead of <. This will solve Your problem, and make sure you understand why will the following code would work. I would recommand you to use a paper and pencil and start writing down the values of i and sum after every iteration.

```
for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) { 
    sum += i;
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Why is this not sufficient? Including or excluding zero from the loop isn't going to affect the sum.

Comment: @khelwood - Ah, you have a good point there! Because `i` will be `0` and not affect the sum. Still, the extra loop isn't ideal. But you're right, this does solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are incrementing the value of `i` before adding it to `sum` in the `while` loop, the same thing needs to be done in case of `for` loop as well. Given below is the implementation using the `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; i++ < number; ){
    sum += i;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```